# actualización de año automáticamente dentro de un input en html

Tags: javascript, html, input

tengo un input tipo text, con un value "31/12/2023" readonly quisiera saber como puedo hacer para que dentro del input se modifique automáticamente el año pero el mes y el día queden iguales, tengo algo así:

```
<div class="form-group has-float-label">
 <input tabindex="8" name="txtFechaFinal" type="text" value="31/12/2023" id="fechaFinal" autocomplete="off" readonly placeholder=" " class="form-control InputPading limpiar" required/>
</div>
```

lo que necesito es que el año se modifique automáticamente por ejemplo este es 2023, el siguiente 2024 y asi sucesivamente, pero el día y el mes quede por default 31/12

Comment: "Se modifique automáticamente por ejemplo este es 2023, el siguiente..." El siguiente qué? Input? No se entiende el problema.

Comment: ¿Qué haz intentado hacer? Por favor lee [ask]

Comment: var today = new Date();
    var anyoActual = today.getFullYear();
    var nuevoValor = "31/12/" + anyoActual;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var today = new Date();
    var anyoActual = today.getFullYear();
    var nuevoValor = "31/12/" + anyoActual;
    //Y luego asignarle este valor a tu input por JS 
  
    $('#id').val(nuevoValor);
    //En caso de que no tengas JQuery, puedes hacerlo con vanilla JS asi:
    document.getElementById("id").value=nuevoValor;
```

Para hacer esto lo único que se necesita es ponerle un id al input de modo que quede así:

```
 <input tabindex="8" id="txtFechaFinal" name="txtFechaFinal" type="text" value="31/12/2023" id="fechaFinal" autocomplete="off" readonly placeholder=" " class="form-control InputPading limpiar" required/>
```